# How borked is my attempted notation for a multilevel gamma regression with AR(1) autocorrelated residuals?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm, gamma-distribution, notation

I have no math background and am in way over my head trying to figure out the correct notation for my model: a multilevel random-slopes gamma regression with log link and AR(1) autocorrelated residuals. There is one predictor $x$ measured several times per individual, separated into within- and between-person components.

If possible, I much prefer the notation style [Richard McElreath](https://youtu.be/zYYBtxHWE0A?si=-RS-8OoW_yCE1S5c&t=2965) uses where the error does not need to be its own category of thing, as opposed to the $y = bx + \varepsilon$ style. However, I'm having a hard time finding examples of this kind of model written out using this notation (either for gamma regression or for autocorrelated errors, much less both).

Can anyone tell me if the following is correct? Thanks very much for any help, or pointers for where to look further.

$$
\begin{align}
& y \sim \mbox{Gamma}(k, \theta), \\ \\
& \log \{ E(y \mid X = x_{it}) \} = k\theta = (\beta_{0} + \mu_{0i}) + (\beta_{1} + \mu_{1i})(x_{it} - \bar{x}_{i}) + \beta_{2}\bar{x}_i, \\
& \mbox{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1}) = \begin{bmatrix}
k\theta^2 & \rho k\theta^2 \\
\rho k\theta^2 & k\theta^2
\end{bmatrix},  \\ 
& \mu_{0i} \sim N(0, \sigma_0), \\
& \mu_{1i} \sim N(0, \sigma_1), \\
\end{align}
$$

where $\bar{x}_i$ is the mean of the predictor across all time points (the between-person predictor); $x_{it} - \bar{x}_{i}$ is the deviation from a person's mean (the within-person predictor); $\mu_{0i}$ is the random intercept and $\mu_{1i}$ is their random slope (both normally distributed); and $\rho$ is an AR(1) autocorrelation parameter estimated per participant.